# onBackPressed does not work while there is markers in google map on android

Tags: android, google-maps, onbackpressed

I am trying to exit an `Activity` which is using `googlemap`. I am checking the `isDrawerOpen` state of `DrawerLayout`, `isShown` state of `FloatingActionMenu` in the `onBackPressed` method. These two type of checking is working well, but when there is markers on google map, the `onBackPressed` method does not work.

Here is my code of `onBackPressed` method. I implemented an `exit` method to close the `Activity` if the `DrawerLayout` and the `FloatingActionMenu` are not opened.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else if (menuRed.isShown()) {
            menuRed.close(true);
        } else {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            HomeActivity.this.finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

        }
    }
```

Can anyone tell me how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this on backpress:

```
finish();
startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
```